# Failed to resolve SDK

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, sdk, option-type

On my first post I am using Inteliij and I have problem with my project. I was make project in Spring Boot. All works fine on this computer. Today when I copy this project from my computer to another I have a trouble when i try run project with "Failed to resolve SDK try to Find SDK". When i click on blue link, it dosn't work.

[image: information about problem].

I am checking Settings=>build..=>compiler=>java compiler.[java compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCw27.png) and project structure=>SDKs. [SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdAOA.png)All looks like good. I don't have any idea why this dosn't work. Maybe someone have similar problem and You know how to solve this issue.

Thanks.

EDIT:
[GatePass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpKck.png)

Comment: Try to close the project (File | Close Project), close the IDE, open the project in OS file manager and delete the .idea directory. Re-import the project as per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#open-project and configure JDK from scratch under (File | Project Structure | SDKs) and (File | Project Structure | Project)

Comment: You are awesome! Now i can run my project! Thanks

Comment: It is possible the Run/Debug Configuration settings (copied from another computer?) don't match the project settings

Answer (score 22):

I encountered the same problem as you. My solution is to click Edit Configurations on the left side of the run button, and select to modify jdk in the pop-up interface.

[image]

Comment: Oh man, that's silly. This is the accepted answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check the path on Run/debug configuration dialog:
[image]

Comment: How can it be opened? Please add a little more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Your Intellij is set to use the SDK but your project isn't.
File -> Project structure -> Project -> Project SDK
[image]

Comment: I have choosed SDK on 18. I was trying change to another java version, but I still have this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same message while running the Flink java project in InteliiJ Idea.
I deleted the .idea folder from project and rebuild the project. Then it resolved.

[image]

Comment: Remove .idea folder, rebuild the project and try again.